# multiple softmax classifications (Keras)

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to construct a CNN that will output 2 labels, where each label has 12 possibilities; the input is an image.

In other words, my desired output is A (one out of 12 options) and B (one out of 12 **different** options).

With each label separately, the go-to is of course softmax, but I couldn't find whether it is possible to do 'multiple softmax' labels like that.

Clearly, I can output 24 neurons, using sigmoid outputs and then normalize manually, but then the network will not intrinsically couple the 12 options within each group.

I'm writing pseudo-pseudo-code of what I would have wanted, if it existed:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(64, kernel_size=3,activation='relu', input_shape=image_shape))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256,activation='relu'))
# pseudo-pseudo-code
model.add(Dense((12,12),activation=('softmax','softmax'))) # <- here is where I would have liked 2 softmax outputs with 12 neurons in each
```

Any solutions will be welcome (I'm using Keras but will be happy for solutions using any other package, or even code something myself).

Edit: I could also generate 144 outputs representing all combinations, but I am not sure whether this would be a good solution - any comment on that is also very welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the functional API with 2 outputs. Guide in https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models

something on the lines of:

```
input = Input(input_shape=image_shape)
cnv = Convolution2d(...)(input)
hidden = Dense(256, ...)(Flatten()(cnv))
output1 = Dense(12, activation='softmax')(hidden)
output2 = Dense(12, activation='softmax')(hidden)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=[output1, output2])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'binary_crossentropy'],
              loss_weights=[1., 1.])
```

Comment: Thanks! This does look like what I was looking for - I will read the guide and try to implement it.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes and reads this, `loss` should be `categorical_crossentropy` rather than binary

Comment: Is the output of output2 based on the output of output1? For example, you got label "C" at output1, then the second output comes from the 12 labels from "C"? if each output 1 label has 12 sublabels.

Comment: @TheJokerAEZ In the example above output2 is not directly dependent on output1; but nothing prevents you from build a different example where output2 takes output1 as (one of its) inputs(s).